# Unable to connect to selected target: Connection failed: connect timed out

Tags: device-driver, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

Blackberry10 issue:

I'm using blackberry native SDK-beta1.

When I run my application using Wi-Fi or USBport on real device, error "**Unable to connect to selected target: Connection failed: connect timed out**" is shown. 
I build my application successfully, I've set the building mode device-release. Developer mode is on in device. Both targets (Wi-Fi & USB) are created properly; Wi-Fi in on; USB cable is connected succefully (I get notification by Device manager also). But still I get this error.

Sometimes **making no change in this scenario gives me successful** downloading & installation of application in device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pinging device using cmd & check if you receive any reply. If it does, try cleaning your project or rebooting the device & run again. Its a beta version so it may hung sometimes.